# Query Overpass turbo by lat/lon to find specific tags

Tags: gps, openstreetmap, overpass-api

so Im attempting to use overpass to find the state and postal code based upon long and lat coordinates.

I know if I run the following, I can find at least the state name in what is reported. But I have no idea how to just search for the specific tag I want and only have that be returned.

```
    [out:json];
    is_in(39.767145, -86.158836);
    (._;>;);
    out;
```

I also dont know how to find the postal code yet but I assume once I do I can use the same solution here to extract that information.

I have tried searching through various other posts here and on other message boards but no one was doing exactly what I am doing. So none of the solutions were able to truly help